# Como utilizar Try/Catch em leitura de arquivos

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch

Possuo um método chamado `readFileCredentials` que tem o objetivo de abrir um arquivo e retornar os dados que estavam dentro desse arquivo, segue o código desse método:

```
readFileCredentials = function(file, cb){
    var _path = 'data-source/credentials/' + file;
    fs.readFile(_path, 'utf8', function(err, data){
        cb(err, data); 
    });
};
```

E para chamar esse método, eu construi esse código:

```
try{    
    readFileCredentials('arquivo.txt', function(err, data){
         console.log('Abriu');
    });
}catch(err){
    console.log('Não abriu');
}
```

A leitura está funcionando, porém, quando envio um nome de arquivo errado, para que haja um erro, o catch não é acionado, o que há de errado?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O método [`fs.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback) já faz isso por ti, para evitar gerar erros que parem o código. A tua ideia é boa, mas não é precisa. Podes dar uma olhada ao [código fonte do `fs` no Github](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js).

O que seria apanhado no `catch` é passado à variável `err`, por isso, a tua lógica deve depender dessa variável e não de um `try`/`catch`:

Podes fazer assim por exemplo:

```
fs.readFile(_path, 'utf8', function(err, data){
    console.log(err ? 'Nao abriu' : 'Abriu');
    cb(err, data); 
});
```

Comment: Não conhecia isto, é legal o JS fazer a coisa certa que é difícil de encontrar em outras linguagens. Pena que o exemplo do *link* dá um `throw` estragando tudo :D (claro que tem situação que o `throw` pode ser adequado). Ah, é Node, por isso eu não conhecia.

Comment: @bigown é o Node deu uns passos interessantes para melhor em relação ao JS nativo e a maneira de tratar ficheiros.

Comment: Imagino, pq o JS normal em *browser* tem que ser bem limitado mesmo :)